# How do I uninstall software that has 2 uninstall strings using batch file?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, batch-file

Can someone please offer any advice on how to uninstall the below two strings at the same time using a batch file?

```
MsiExec.exe /i{5577B8F7-A4A8-451E-BDE1-471E52825904}

"C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information\{4D9CA1B8-5FF5-47A7-8BDF-C37D1F9F55A5}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly -uninst
```

Comment: At the same time isn't possible if you mean in parallel - by using a batch it means one will execute after the other

Comment: Yes I meant in parallel, one after the other but running in a quiet mode

Comment: No, you mean in serial :)

Comment: yes, one after the other

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch them both at the same time then use `start`

```
start MsiExec.exe /i{5577B8F7-A4A8-451E-BDE1-471E52825904}
start "" "C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information{4D9CA1B8-5FF5-47A7-8BDF-C37D1F9F55A5}\setup.exe" -runfromtemp -l0x0009 -removeonly -uninst
```

However, if they are both MSI, you might get an error on one saying it can't uninstall until the other has finished.

Comment: How do I create a batch file to unistall them as one is MSI and the other is .exe file?

Comment: Put those commands in a notepad file and save it as `filename.bat` then run it. I presumed those were the right commands that you posted so I just copied and pasted them, to run an MSI in quiet mode I think you need the `/q` switch, type `msiexec` at a cmd prompt for all the options.

Comment: I can unistall the first string no problem, but the second one is my problem and I'd like to unistall them both in a quiet mode using a batch file. Can you help Bali?

Comment: It depends if the uninstaller needs user interaction. When you run the second one do you have to click on a GUI or do something yourself to get it to uninstall?

Comment: It doesn't need user interaction, it's coming up with the unistall window that I have to click on next to unistall.

Comment: Then that is user interaction :) the only way to do it silently is for the app to have a built in functionality to do that. Check the app docs, if it doesn't have an option for this then I'm afraid your out of luck.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421306/installshield-silent-uninstall-not-working-at-command-line to uninstall InstallShield quietly